# DataGridView change CurrentCell while changing CurrentCell

Tags: .net, datagridview

An "Inception" Problem.

A DataGridView is bounded to a child class of an BindingList ("Sorted"). The class "Sorted" take care of ordering the data. When data in "Sorted" was changed, the "Sorted" class move the current data to the correct position. The data in the DataGridView also changes, so this is OK.

Example:

```
A
C
B <- current entry.
```

After cell leave:

```
A
B
C
```

But.. when a user change data that causes a row move and leave the cell, the next active cell (focus) is the next cell in the same row. But I want to set the focus to the cell in the new row.

Example:

```
A 1
C 2
B 0 
^ focus
```

Press Tab / Enter:

```
A 1
B 0
C 2 
  ^ focus
```

But I want to set the focus to:

```
A 1
B 0
  ^ focus
C 2
```

Calculating the correct cell isn't the problem (The "Sorted" list executes an event). But in which event can I set the correct CurrentCell? Every event I tried ends with a bit flickering or an Exception saying that CurrentCell could not be set here because of recursion.

Answer (score 1):

A very dirty but working solution:

```
private DataGridViewCell ThreadCellSelect = null;
private void SetNextCell(DataGridViewCell newSelection)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadSetDGVCell));
    ThreadCellSelect = newSelection;
    t.Start();
}
private void ThreadSetDGVCell()
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1); // next time slice
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { ThreadSetDGVCell(); });
    } else
    {
        if (ThreadCellSelect != null)
        {
            this.CurrentCell = ThreadCellSelect;
            ThreadCellSelect = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly for the exact same problem I was having as OP.